# Web browser not opening using Watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I'm trying to open my browser using Watir with Ruby. I was able to run my script and open the browser once. Now I'm getting the error:

```
#<Watir::Browser:0x586947ae595497d2 url="data:," title="">
```

Title should be equal to "data." Chrome will open and then close without actually traveling to a webpage.

These were my steps after installing watir and chromedriver
1) rails c. 2) browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)

I'm following a tutorial: https://youtu.be/1UYBAn69Qrk?t=4m24s

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The behaviours you mentioned are not particularly abnormal. The error mentioned is just the inspection of the browser object. Chromedriver by default will close when the session ends. You mention the browser closing without actually traveling, but you don't mention calling the `goto` method. It would help if you could elaborate on the problem so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: show us the code that is causing the error... we know you are following a tutorial, but that does not mean you have necessarily copied the code faithfully or modified it correctly to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake on my part, chromedriver wasn't properly installed. I came across [this](http://codrspace.com/rails4sandeep/install-and-set-path-to-chromedriver-on-mac-or-linux/) post. Here are the steps I took:

```
$ cd $HOME/Downloads
$ wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.20/chromedriver_mac32.zip
$ unzip chromedriver_mac32.zip
$ mkdir -p $HOME/bin
$ mv chromedriver $HOME/bin
$ echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin" >> $HOME/.bash_profile
```